# How to add bullet point in rtf file in ruby

Tags: ruby, rtf, bulletedlist

This is working code to add the paragraph in rtf file.

```
document = Document.new(Font.new(Font::ROMAN, 'Times new Roman'))

@drugs.each do |drug|
  document.paragraph(styles['NORMAL']) do |p|
    p << "#{drug.name}"       
  end
end
```

Current display format is listed below:

```
drug one

drug two 

drug three
```

However,required display format is:

- first drug
- second drug
- third drug

Comment: What is `Font`? Are you using [this ruby gem](https://github.com/dj2/Ruby-RTF)? Or maybe [this one](https://github.com/clbustos/rtf)? Can you please provide a [complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, so we can properly understand the question?

Comment: Thank you @tom lord i am using the [this one](https://github.com/clbustos/rtf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is using [the `'rtf'` ruby gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/rtf/versions/0.3.3), so my following answer is based on this.

There may be other libraries available to solve this problem, or you could even consider [writing your own solution, based on the RTF specification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17373327/1954610).

Unfortunately, the README of both the [original project](https://github.com/thechrisoshow/rtf) and the [official "bug fix" fork](https://github.com/clbustos/rtf) do not mention how to format bullet points with the library. (Also, neither projects have been updated in about 5 years...) The github code was originally copied from [this ruby-forge project](http://ruby-rtf.rubyforge.org/docs/index.html), which also does not mention bullet points.

In times like this, you unfortunately need to dig in to the actual source code to find out what's supported by the library - and sure enough, you'll find [`RTF::ListTable`](https://github.com/thechrisoshow/rtf/blob/master/lib/rtf/list.rb) which seems to handle bullet points.

**However**, you will not find this in your version of the library. This github version of the gem appears to be [uploaded as a different ruby gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/clbustos-rtf). To use this updated version of the library, you will need the [**`clbustos-rtf`**](https://rubygems.org/gems/clbustos-rtf) gem instead.

Comment: Thank you again and does the [clbustos-rtf](https://rubygems.org/gems/clbustos-rtf)  gem  supports the bullet point easily ?

Comment: Can you please have a go at this yourself, first? I'm not providing a free code writing service :) ... But glancing at the source code, it appears to support bullet points, which can be labelled either with a "disk", "hyphen" or "decimal".