# RTF Numbered List Example

Tags: document, rtf, documentation-generation

It seems impossible to find a very simple working example for an RTF numbered list that looks like this:

```
1. The first line
2. The second line
```

I tried to make a small sample by using Word but they produce a lot of garbage. Can anyone help out?

Somewhere I got this, but it's not working, only the first line is bulleted, more lines get appended to the first line.

```
\pard{\pntext\f0 1.\tab}\*\pn\pnlvlbody\pnf0\pnindent0\pnstart1\pndec{\pntxta.}}\fi-360\li480\sa50\sl0\slmult1 The first line
```

(My target is the RTF Edit box of Windows, so I'm not all concerned about backwards compatibility with older RTF readers like Word 6 which do not understand numbered lists and need fallback text formatted to look list numbers.)

Comment: Of course tongue in cheek referencing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367975/rtf-bullet-list-example which works very well for me for bulleted lists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me with the Windows RichTextBox control and Word version 1803:

```
{\rtf1
\pard{\pntext\f0 1.\tab}\*\pn\pnlvlbody\pnf0\pnindent0\pnstart1\pndec{\pntxta.}
\fi-360\li480\sa50\sl0\slmult1 The first line\par The second line\par The third line\par
\pard\par normal text
}
```

Inconsistencies come when you try to end the list without a blank line between the last list item and the normal text - Word displays it correctly, but the RTB control still shows "normal text" as part of the list (i.e. number `4.`) if you remove the `\par` after `\pard`.

[image: numbered list in RTB control]

Comment: Thanks a lot for that `\pard\par` tip!

Comment: This does not render the same output with WordPad on Windows 10, or with LibreOffice. Only the first line has a number.