# TRichEdit: Different bullets according to how much the paragraph is indented?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria, trichedit

In a 32-bit VCL Application in Windows 10 in Delphi 11 Alexandria, I use the new `TRichEdit` control. I have the following code to INDENT the current paragraph:

```
procedure TformMain.menuitemIndentDecreaseClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  richeditNotesEditor.Paragraph.FirstIndent := richeditNotesEditor.Paragraph.FirstIndent - 10;
  menuitemIndentDecrease.Enabled := richeditNotesEditor.Paragraph.FirstIndent > 9;
end;

procedure TformMain.menuitemIndentIncreaseClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  richeditNotesEditor.Paragraph.FirstIndent := richeditNotesEditor.Paragraph.FirstIndent + 10;
  menuitemIndentDecrease.Enabled := True;
end;
```

It works well:

[image]

However, each indented paragraph uses the same bullet. How can I automatically have different bullets according to how much the paragraph is indented?

Comment: To 90%, this isn't a Delphi question but a Win32 question, since the [`TRichEdit`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TRichEdit) is merely a fairly thin wrapper for the Win32 [RICHEDIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/rich-edit-controls) control. And that question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367975/rtf-bullet-list-example). So to 90%, this Q is a duplicate. Basically, it seems like the bullet is stored (rather non-semantically) as a character in the RTF.

Comment: Bonus hint: Try Shift+Ctrl+L in a TRichEdit.

Comment: (But the old Q is more about the RTF code than the Win32 control's API.)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Shift+Ctrl+L only selects the current line. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I know that `TRichEdit` is a wrapper of the Windows control. Nevertheless, I am curious about how to achieve what I want with Delphi code.

Comment: Really? Shift+Ctrl+L is supposed to cycle through all bullet and number styles. (There is only a single bullet style but many numbering styles.)

Comment: Yes, but there is no TRichEdit-specific solution for this, so you'll need to use the Win32 API. And so the solution will be exactly the same in C, C++, Delphi, etc.

Comment: Still, +1 for an interesting question. As hinted above, I cannot find any other Q which is about changing bullet style programmatically.

Comment: Even in WORDPAD editing an RTF file, Shift+Ctrl+L only selects the current line.

Comment: Maybe this depends on your locale (Austria). In English and Swedish, it is Shift+Ctrl+L. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JV67s.gif

Comment: I changed the bullet style of a single paragraph in WordPad: https://i.imgur.com/f4gpmYm.png and then loaded the RTF saved from Wordpad in Delphi's `TRichEdit`: The changed bullet-style was preserved. So this is proof that WordPad uses the same new RichEdit control as Delphi 11 Alexandria. So, what is possible in WordPad (changing bullet-style) should also be possible in Delphi.

Comment: Of course, it's the same Rich Edit. (But beware that this control exists in several different versions.)

Comment: I've found the culprit: It was a system-wide macro. Now I've deactivated that system-wide macro, and now Shift+Ctrl+L does work as intended. Thank you for that hint! Now I only need to access any of these bullet styles explicitly from my own controls, like in WordPad.

Comment: I'm a bit busy right now, but maybe I'll get some time to investigate this (very interesting question) later this week.